# Set random seed for cirq functions

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computing, cirq

I am working with cirq and use a random unitary for testing purposes with:

```
random_matrix = cirq.testing.random_unitary(dim=4)
```

where can can the random seed for this function be set, using `random.seed(a=1)` does not seem to do this.

Comment: Solved: use np.random.seed() not random.seed()

Comment: When you have found the solution, you can also add an answer (answer your own question), which you can then accept for other people who have the same problem. In a answer, it is more meaningful than in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cirq relies on numpy for its random functions, so using:

```
np.random.seed(2)
```

Sets the seed for cirq

Comment: To follow up, the documentation describing this is here https://quantumai.google/cirq/simulation:

"The actual measurement results depend on the seeding from random seed generator (numpy) . You can set this using numpy.random_seed."